# Finding multiple local maxima and placing data labels on corresponding chart

Tags: excel, vba, graph

[image: Ro-Vibrational Chemistry Nonsense]

Hello,

I have found that

```
=IF(AND(C4>C3,C4>C5),"Local maxima","")
```

along with:

```
Sub CustomLabels()

   Dim i, myCount, pt
   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("myChart").Activate
   myCount = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count

   For i = 1 To myCount
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).ApplyDataLabels
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Text = Range("D" & i + 1).Value
   Next i

End Sub
```

Yields something that looks like this:
[image: What you get with current code]

What I would like to do is get those labels that say "max" to say the actual values, preferably the x and y values, but just the y works too. Additionally it would be nice to print those maxima to a few cells at the top of the page. Finally, since there are 10000 values, I need to find a way to filter out the "noise." I have a dilemma. If it is impossible then I understand, but I would appreciate any help.

All the best,

N

Comment: You've definitely been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: I'm a little rusty on syntax. I haven't tried VBA since my last post, which was ~2.5 years ago. You are right though. I will give it my best shot and get back. I just didn't want to get into it if my thought process is wrong and there is a better, more straight-forward way. My lack of a solution is not from lack of trying though I assure you.